Impurity Av Ha-Tuma
Im not talking about today, I just want to know the law:
Lets say a mourner/sister of the deceased went to cemetery and did not take a shower, couple of days later they pour olive oil into another persons food. Is the second person now considered to be impure? In another word, did the impurity transfered from the mourner to the second person? Ty for any explanation

I would refer to Mishneh Torah, Tuamat Met ch. 5.  https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1517169/jewish/Tumat-Met-Chapter-5.htm
The worst-case scenario in the given situation is that the mourner has contracted tumah met by visiting the gravesite, and while still impure, touches a vessel (kli) which contains olive oil, and the second person touches (or is deemed to touch) the kli.
I would say, the second person is not made impure.

When, by contrast, one touches keilim that were touched by an impure
person or one touches a person who touches keilim that touched a
corpse, he is exempt, as we explained in Hilchot Bi'at HaMikdash.

But the kli and olive oil have a first-degree derivative of impurity.
